# MobileFirst SAP Adapter http POST requests

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, netweaver

How do we pass header such as "content-type" in a SAP NW Adapter? I have to implement a $batch request from a MobileFirst hybrid app and for this need to set the content-type from the request.

How is that possible?

I have searched through adapter documentation and nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to pass any headers to SAP NW adapters. If you're using v7.0, you might be able to make use of the RESTful Adapter Wizard along with Java adapters to pass the headers you're referring to: [https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_impl_java_adapter_JAXRS.html](http://It's%20not%20possible%20to%20pass%20any%20headers%20to%20SAP%20NW%20adapters.%20If%20you're%20using%20v7.0,%20you%20might%20be%20able%20to%20make%20use%20of%20the%20RESTful%20Adapter%20Wizard%20along%20with%20Java%20adapters%20to%20pass%20the%20headers%20you're%20referring%20to:%20https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_impl_java_adapter_JAXRS.html)

Comment: Hello Kyle, I am using v6.3. Is there a way I can implement a batch request in SAP NW Adapters as I need to post multiple objects to SAP system. How can I do so without setting the content- type in header? Please guide